# Azure az container create does not finish with try to mount a volume

Tags: azure, docker

I'm using Azure Container instances and Container registries to deploy apps.
I have create few of the throught the web interface and those work fine,
but for some others I need data persistance, hence I have to mount a volume,
that part I'm not finding it straght forward.

The following code works without any issue:

```
/home/luis/bin/az container create \
    --resource-group mlcontainers2 \
    --name modeldiagnosticsvolume \
    --image mlcontainers2.azurecr.io/samples/modeldiagnostics \
    --registry-login-server mlcontainers2.azurecr.io \
    --registry-password XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   \
    --registry-username mlcontainers2 \
    --ports 80 5000 5100 \
    --ip-address public
```

But when I add the lines to mount a volume:

```
--azure-file-volume-account-name cs217dfd5a81083x41faxb08 
--azure-file-volume-account-key  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
--azure-file-volume-share-name mlstorage 
--azure-file-volume-mount-path app/data
```

New code been:

```
/home/luis/bin/az container create \
    --resource-group mlcontainers2 \
    --name modeldiagnosticsvolume \
    --image mlcontainers2.azurecr.io/samples/modeldiagnostics \
    --registry-login-server mlcontainers2.azurecr.io \
    --registry-password XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   \
    --registry-username mlcontainers2 \
    --ports 80 5000 5100 \
    --ip-address public \
    --azure-file-volume-account-name cs217dfd5a81083x41faxb08 \
    --azure-file-volume-account-key  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \
    --azure-file-volume-share-name mlstorage \
    --azure-file-volume-mount-path app/data 


The process goes for over half an  hour and just shows:

 - Running ..


 - Running ..
 - Running ..
```

In the Azure portal interface that the status of that container is: "Pending"

And if I stop to process and try to restart it, I get the following error:

The container group 'modeldiagnosticsvolume' is still transitioning, please retry later.

And I have to change the name to be able to try it again, but the result is the same

```
 - Running ..


 - Running ..
 - Running ..
```

EDIT:

I leave it running an got this other error:

```
Deployment failed. Correlation ID: 6012f7c9-6241-4bfb-8322-c7f052523da0. Operation failed with status: 200. Details: Resource state Failed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your issue, the possible reason is that you did not use the right mount path. It should an absolute path such as `/app/data`. So the CLI command would like below:

```
/home/luis/bin/az container create \
    --resource-group mlcontainers2 \
    --name modeldiagnosticsvolume \
    --image mlcontainers2.azurecr.io/samples/modeldiagnostics \
    --registry-login-server mlcontainers2.azurecr.io \
    --registry-password XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   \
    --registry-username mlcontainers2 \
    --ports 80 5000 5100 \
    --ip-address public \
    --azure-file-volume-account-name cs217dfd5a81083x41faxb08 \
    --azure-file-volume-account-key  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \
    --azure-file-volume-share-name mlstorage \
    --azure-file-volume-mount-path /app/data
```

And there one more advice, you'd better add the image tag when you use the image. If you do not use the tag, the default one is latest. It will cause the errors if there is no latest tag. For more details, see [Mount an Azure file share in Azure Container Instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-volume-azure-files).

Comment: Just spend five hours figuring out the same issue... really bad error information and Azure not giving any feedback for such a small thing :(